# Pagination with Viewpager

Tags: android, pagination, android-viewpager, lazy-loading

I am having a ViewPager and  i am getting huge amount of data from API response, so i am looking forward to implement Pagination with my ViewPager items as i could load only 20 items at a time and once the user is at the last item we can show a loader for a bit and can load the next set of data, as my app is using more memory on the device.

I have researched and found Pagination for RecyclerView but couldn't find relevant resources to use with ViewPager.
Anybody who have worked on similar kind of requirement can guide me with the steps to achieve the same.

Comment: my suggestion use this library https://github.com/alirezat775/carousel-view, that's helpful for implementation lazyload

Answer (score 0):

Try to use View Pager 2 that uses the same adapter as recycler view

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create custom pagination with viewpager. Suppose you get 10 item first time then put a condition that if viewpager current position is 8 then call another slot of api which will get data 11 to 20 and so on.

Comment: Yes i can do it this way, but thought if there is a standard way of achieving this.

Comment: But it is less complex and giving good result, and if you try any library go in the library and can check you will find this type of code there.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still wants to solve this problem, just use paging 3, if your api supports pagination. Then create PagingAdapter and connect it to ViewPager2.

Paging3 guide:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30995722)